# Reading a DWORD Date From Registry Using Python & _winreg

Tags: python, python-2.7, dword, winreg

I'm trying to read a DWORD date from the Windows registry using Python's [`_winreg.QueryValueEx`](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html?highlight=queryvalueex#_winreg.QueryValueEx) and I can't get the correct format.

```
DWORD Value: 5116e300

Output using _winreg.QueryValueEx: 1360454400

Desired Output: 2/10/2013
```

Can I use [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime) somehow?

Thank you

---

Edit

[kindall's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885031/1061279) worked below.

The final line used was the following:

```
import time

t = 1360454400
print time.strftime("%m/%d/%y", time.gmtime(t))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you pretty close:

```
import time

t = 1360454400
print time.strftime("%m/%d/%y", time.gmtime(t))
```

To get it without the leading zeroes:

```
t = time.gmtime(t)
print "%d/%d/%2d" % (t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday, t.tm_year % 100)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your first solution worked.  However, instead of importing `datetime`, I'm importing `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that DWORD value of `5116e300` is actually a value of `1360388864` and not `1360454400`, but anyway...

```
ts = datetime.fromtimestamp(1360454400)

print '{:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(ts) #
# '02/10/2013'
```

or:

```
print '{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}'.format(ts)
# '2/10/2013'
```